# Integral of a Gaussian with Trigonometric functions Involved

Tags: integration, asymptotics, approximation, gaussian-integral

I am having a difficult time evaluating an integral unlike any integral I have seen before. To get right into things here is the integral:

$$\frac{A}{\sigma_o\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty [\sin(kx)-A\delta\sin^2(kx)]e^{-\left(\frac{(x-x')^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)[1-2A\delta\sin(kx)]}dx$$

One very important thing to know about this is that $\delta$ is very small, so any term with $\delta^2$ can be immediately thrown out.

Previously I had solved this integral by distributing the exponent, then splitting that up into two exponents:

$$e^{-\left(\frac{(x-x')^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)}e^{A\delta\sin(kx)\left(\frac{(x-x')^2}{\sigma^2}\right)}$$

Then I used a Taylor series on the second exponent to write it as:

$$1+A\delta\sin(kx)\left(\frac{(x-x')^2}{\sigma^2}\right)$$
You can ignore the remaining terms because they involve $\delta^2$ . From here I was able to solve the integral. However the solution did not give me the correct answer so I concluded that the Taylor series was not an appropriate approximation.

So from here I've gotten stuck. I don't know how to integrate a gaussian with $\sin(kx)$ in the exponent, and I don't know of any other way to get it out of there. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated and I'll do my best to answer any questions.

Comment: One thing that is not immediately clear to me about your question is whether you require an *exact* evaluation of your integral for *any* $\delta$, or you need an *asymptotic* expansion of your integral for $\delta\to 0$...

Comment: @PierpaoloVivo I require an exact evaluation of this integral for any $\delta$

Comment: You say $\delta$ is small, but is $A\delta$ small, as that's the factor appearing inside the integral ?

Comment: @StephenG $A\delta$ is not as small, and I'm assuming that's the reason the Taylor series didn't work. $\delta$ is on the order of $10^{-5}$ and $A\delta$ is on the order of $10^{-2}$

Comment: @YoungPhysicist. Is there any reason why you expect an exact evaluation of your integral to be possible at all? The reason I am asking is because the much neater integrals $$
\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \sin (x) \exp \left(-\frac{1}{2} x^2 (1-\sin (x))\right) \, dx
$$ and even $$
\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \exp \left(-\frac{1}{2} x^2 (1-\sin (x))\right) \, dx
$$ do not seem to have a closed-form solution either...so I am highly skeptical (to say the least) that your beast may turn out to be exactly solvable...

Comment: @PierpaoloVivo To be honest, I don't really know if it will be solvable or not. I'm just hoping that it is. I guess for me seeing that the integral with the Taylor series was solvable made me believe that the integral would be solvable without it, but no I don't have a reason to say that it should definitely be solvable.

Comment: The problem with taylorexpansion is not really that $\delta A \sim 10^{-2}$ but more that the  $\delta A (x-x')$ explodes for $x-x'>>1$ I would instead use the fact the the intefgrand is sharply peaked around $x=x'$ and perform an expanison in this parameter $x=x'+\Delta x$ and maybe use an expansion in $\delta A$ as second step.

Comment: See how nice the function is peaked :)

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot[%28sin%28x%29-0.1sin^2%28x%29%29%29e^%28-%28x-1%29^2%281-0.1+sin%28x%29%29%29%2C+{x%2C-5%2C5}]

Comment: @tired I see what you're saying about how the function is peaked around $x=x'$ but I'm a little confused by what you mean by expansion in the parameter of $x=x'+\Delta x$ could you explain this a bit more?

Comment: We say that the main contribution comes from the point $x=x'$ and we only need to take a small neigbourhood into account. this can in many cases be made rigourous by the method of seepest descent.

Comment: @tired I considered changing the limits of integration from $-\infty$ and $\infty$ to something less because this would most likely be sufficient, but that doesn't help me with the actual integration of this integral. I'm not familiar with the method of steepest descent though so I don't know how that would go for me

Comment: Try for yourself, if u don't get anything i can try tomorrow but i'm quiet confident that the approach should work

Comment: @tired I have attempted to use the method of steepest descent but still couldn't get a good result. If you (or anyone else) could help me with this it would be very much appreciated

Comment: Would u mind to update ur answer with the attempts u made? this will makes things easier for me.

Comment: @tired I attempted separated the exponent as shown in my original post to get the integrand into the form

$$g(x)e^{\lambda f(x)}$$

with

$$g(x)=(\sin(kx)-A\delta\sin^2 (kx))e^{-(x-x')^2 /(2\sigma^2)}$$

$$f(x)=(\delta/\sigma^2) \sin(kx)(x-x')^2$$

$$\lambda=A$$

Comment: From here I used Laplace's method calling $x=x'$ the interior point that is the maximum. The answer seemed to look alright until I ended up with an imaginary number in the denominator

$$\sqrt{2\pi}(\sin(kx')-A\delta\sin^2 (kx'))/\sqrt{-2A(\delta/\sigma^2)\sin(kx')}$$